# Why error occurs when adding a manifest CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT or CAPTURE_SECURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT?

Tags: android, screenshot, screen-capture

Faced with such a problem. With the implementation of this piece of code, an exception:

DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            int mDensity = displayMetrics.densityDpi;

```
        DisplayManager dM = (DisplayManager) getSystemService(ContextWrapper.DISPLAY_SERVICE);

        ImageReader imR = ImageReader.newInstance(300, 300, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 2);


        VirtualDisplay vD = dM.createVirtualDisplay("VladScreen", 300, 300, mDensity, imR.getSurface(), DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PUBLIC);
```

The exception is as follows:

```
 java.lang.SecurityException: Requires CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT or CAPTURE_SECURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT permission, or an appropriate MediaProjection token in order to create a screen sharing virtual display.
09-27 04:03:30.321 7739-7739/com.example.novoseltsev.applicationpopupwindow W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
09-27 04:03:30.321 7739-7739/com.example.novoseltsev.applicationpopupwindow W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
09-27 04:03:30.321 7739-7739/com.example.novoseltsev.applicationpopupwindow W/System.err:     at android.hardware.display.IDisplayManager$Stub$Proxy.createVirtualDisplay(IDisplayManager.java:484)
09-27 04:03:30.321 7739-7739/com.example.novoseltsev.applicationpopupwindow W/System.err:     at android.hardware.display.DisplayManagerGlobal.createVirtualDisplay(DisplayManagerGlobal.java:377)
09-27 04:03:30.321 7739-7739/com.example.novoseltsev.applicationpopupwindow W/System.err:     at android.hardware.display.DisplayManager.createVirtualDisplay(DisplayManager.java:537)
09-27 04:03:30.321 7739-7739/com.example.novoseltsev.applicationpopupwindow W/System.err:     at android.hardware.display.DisplayManager.createVirtualDisplay(DisplayManager.java:529)
09-27 04:03:30.321 7739-7739/com.example.novoseltsev.applicationpopupwindow W/System.err:     at android.hardware.display.DisplayManager.createVirtualDisplay(DisplayManager.java:480)
09-27 04:03:30.321 7739-7739/com.example.novoseltsev.applicationpopupwindow W/System.err:     at com.example.novoseltsev.applicationpopupwindow.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:106)
09-27 04:03:30.321 7739-7739/com.example.novoseltsev.applicationpopupwindow W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
09-27 04:03:30.321 7739-7739/com.example.novoseltsev.applicationpopupwindow W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
09-27 04:03:30.321 7739-7739/com.example.novoseltsev.applicationpopupwindow W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
09-27 04:03:30.321 7739-7739/com.example.novoseltsev.applicationpopupwindow W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
09-27 04:03:30.321 7739-7739/com.example.novoseltsev.applicationpopupwindow W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
09-27 04:03:30.321 7739-7739/com.example.novoseltsev.applicationpopupwindow W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
09-27 04:03:30.321 7739-7739/com.example.novoseltsev.applicationpopupwindow W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-27 04:03:30.321 7739-7739/com.example.novoseltsev.applicationpopupwindow W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
09-27 04:03:30.321 7739-7739/com.example.novoseltsev.applicationpopupwindow W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
09-27 04:03:30.321 7739-7739/com.example.novoseltsev.applicationpopupwindow W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-27 04:03:30.321 7739-7739/com.example.novoseltsev.applicationpopupwindow W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
09-27 04:03:30.321 7739-7739/com.example.novoseltsev.applicationpopupwindow W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
09-27 04:03:30.363 7739-11879/com.example.novoseltsev.applicationpopupwindow D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
```

I understand that it is not added to the permisson `CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT` or `CAPTURE_SECURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT`.

But after adding the manifest.xml exception remains

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT"/>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Which android version do you use? If it's Android 6.0 Marshmallow, you need to request permission. [Preference here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: I use Android 5.0.

Answer (score 4):

It's for system services, not for third party's applications.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/display/DisplayManager.html#VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PUBLIC

Creating a public virtual display that isn't restricted to own-content only implicitly creates an auto-mirroring display. See VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR for restrictions on who is allowed to create an auto-mirroring display.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/display/DisplayManager.html#VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR
......
Creating an auto-mirroing virtual display requires the CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT or CAPTURE_SECURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT permission. These permissions are reserved for use by system components and are not available to third-party applications. Alternatively, an appropriate MediaProjection may be used to create an auto-mirroring virtual display.